# Android Layout - Positioning Views based on Horizontal Center

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-edittext, android-relativelayout

I am trying to create a row of four TextViews on the top of the screen.  The row should consist of a TextView to the right, a TextView to the left, and two TextViews adjacent to the right TextView.  For the first two TextViews, the following code works fine:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textViewRight"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:paddingLeft="150dip"
android:text="Right TextView"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
/>
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/textViewLeft"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:text="Left TextView"
android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/textViewRight"
android:paddingRight="150dip"
/>
```

However, when I try to add more TextViews like the following:

```
<EditText
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/textViewRight"
android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/textViewRight"
android:text="TextView L"
android:inputType="number|numberSigned"

/>
<EditText
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textViewRight"
android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/textViewRight"
android:text="TextView R"
android:inputType="number"
    />
```

Nothing changes on the layout preview screen and the two EditTexts are not visible.

How can I make these last two EditTexts appear?  Should I use margins rather than padding?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is the full layout documentation:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >




<TextView
android:id="@+id/textViewRight"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:paddingLeft="150dip"
android:text="Right TextView"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
/>
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/textViewLeft"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:text="Left TextView"
android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/textViewRight"
android:paddingRight="150dip"
/>
<EditText
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/textViewRight"
android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/textViewRight"
android:text="TextView L"
android:inputType="number|numberSigned"

/>
<EditText
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textViewRight"
android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/textViewRight"
android:text="TextView R"
android:inputType="number"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

i dont speak english, but i can help you....using this function... autosize in main.java

```
  public class MAIN extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_prueba_js);


     //               (POSX,POSY,WIDTH,HEIGHT, 0 TO 1....
     AutoSizeAndSetXY(TX1, 0.1,  0.1 , 0.3 , 0.3);
     AutoSizeAndSetXY(TX2, 0.5,  0.1, 0.3 , 0.3 );
     AutoSizeAndSetXY(TX3, 0.1,  0.5 , 0.3 , 0.3);
     AutoSizeAndSetXY(TX4, 0.5,  0.5, 0.3 , 0.3 );
}



      public void AutoSizeAndSetXY(View v,double posX,double posY,double width,double height){
   Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

   int widthP = display.getWidth();
   int heightP = display.getHeight();
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   lp.setMargins(((int)Math.round(posX*widthP)),((int)Math.round(posY*heightP)), 1, 1);
   v.setLayoutParams(lp);
   v.getLayoutParams().height=(int)(Math.round(height*heightP));
   v.getLayoutParams().width=(int)(Math.round(width*widthP));

  }
}
```

Comment: THIS Can be used for buttons, image and others elements

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there will be enough space to add all these guys in one raw, specially for phones, not tablet.

but if you want to do that, it's better to surround your relative layout by horizontal scroll view as in the following layout.

also don't use padding or margins just to push your view to the desired location, it's really considered a bad layout design.

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textViewRight"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Left TextView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textViewRight"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textViewLeft"
        android:inputType="number|numberSigned"
        android:text="TextView L" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editTextLeft"
        android:text="Right TextView" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/textViewRight"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textViewRight"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="TextView R" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this situation I would rather use LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout. And for having same width for editTexts and textViews using layout:weight="1" would be fine. (You can remove weights of some views and set their widths to wrap_content for your needs)

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation="horizantal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewLeft"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Left TextView"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextLeft"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    layout_weight="1"
    android:inputType="number|numberSigned"
    android:text="Left EditText" />



<EditText
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout_weight="1"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:text="Right EditText"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewRight"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Right TextView" />
```